# Is the md5sum linux command working right?

Tags: linux, shell, md5

According to Wikipedia, the md5 sum of an empty string is d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e

I confirmed this with my md5 library

However, when I run

```
echo "" | md5sum
```

in my linux shell, I get 68b329da9893e34099c7d8ad5cb9c940  -

In fact, none of my hashes match the output of the md5sum command.

Any thoughts on this discrepancy?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With that command, you are calculating the md5sum of a single newline character.  Try instead:

```
echo -n "" | md5sum
```

Answer (score 7):

You must eliminate the new line that echo produces

```
$ echo -n '' | md5
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
```

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
echo -n | md5sum
```

Without the '-n', echo outputs a newline, which md5sum duly processes.

Answer (score 2):

use the more portable printf

```
printf "" | md5sum
```